# Get RSS links given a domain

Tags: python, rss, scrapy

I have a file which has a list of domains. I need to crawl the domain(i.e. the whole website) to get rss links. Recursively crawl each page of the website to get rss links from each page and write to a json file corresponding to the domain  This is my code just for one website:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class AppleSpider(CrawlSpider):

  name = 'apple'
  allowed_domains = ['apple.com']
  start_urls = ['http://apple.com']
  #rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]

def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = sel.select('/html/head/link[@type=application/rss+xml]/@href').extract()
    #items = []
    item = AppleItem()
    item['reference_link'] = response.url
    item['rss_link'] = sites
    #items.append(item)
    return item
```

tried running 
    scrapy crawl apple -o items.json -t json

But items.json only contains a bracket [

This is my items.py file:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class AppleItem(Item):
   reference_link = Field()
   rss_link = Field()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression needs to have quotes around the "application/rss+xml" test value.

Try something like:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class AppleItem(Item):
    reference_link = Field()
    rss_link = Field()

class AppleSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'apple'
    allowed_domains = ['apple.com']
    start_urls = ['http://apple.com']
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rsslinks = sel.select('/html/head/link[@type="application/rss+xml"]/@href').extract()
        #items = []
        item = AppleItem()
        item['reference_link'] = response.url
        item['rss_link'] = rsslinks
        #items.append(item)
        return item
```

Comment: It is crawling but file is empty. Is the file populated only after the crawling is over?

Comment: Item are serialized and streamed to the output file but I can't recall how many items the item exporter needs at minimum to start writing

Comment: You can also try out the "JSON lines" exporter so that you can read the file JSON items line by line, 1 item per line. See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format-jsonlines

Comment: I tried this: scrapy crawl apple --set FEED_URI=output.json --set FEED_FORMAT=jsonlines
I didn't get any output